# How Do I Create A List In Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I create a list, I get this error: using the generic type system.collections.generic.list' requires 1' type argument(s)

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class DestroyPotionForever : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static List namesOfDestroyedObjects = new List();
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if(namesOfDestroyedObjects.Count>0){

            for (int i = 0; i < namesOfDestroyedObjects.Count; i++) {
                Destroy(GameObject.Find(namesOfDestroyedObjects[i]));
            }
        }
    }
    void OnTriggerEnter(){
        namesOfDestroyedObjects.Add(this.gameObject.name);
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: `List<string> l = new List<string>();` or whichever type you plan to store in the list. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: If one of the answers solved your question, click the green checkmark to the answer's upper left. If you solved it yourself, type the answer in the Answer box below. You can click the checkmark beside your own answer. Doing either of those tings will mark your question as solved in the UI and search. Putting [SOLVED] in your question or title does not mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare which type your list has. E.g:

```
public static List<string> namesOfDestroyedObjects = new List<string>();
```

By the way you don't need to check :

```
if(namesOfDestroyedObjects.Count>0){}
```

On the first check of the for loop if "namesOfDestroyedObjects.Count" is not greater than 0 then the for loop will break right away.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a list in c#:

```
public static List<T> listName = new List<T>();
```

You must specify the type of `List<>`. Like `List<int>` or `List<Object>`. Depending on your needs.